# How to disable drag drop row from one datagridview to another?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagridview

I have imported "DataGridView" control from Windows form to WPF due to specific reason.
There is customized rows in "DataGridView" like first cell is "ComboBox" with dropdown list and others cells are simple "textBoxes" with readonly mode.
I have placed two customized "DataGridViews" on same Grid(plz refere snapshot).There is one problem when i select comboBox from cell one from any row of "DataGriView1" and hold any item from comboBox,and dragged onto "DataGriView2" then double entries added.
  Actually I don't want to allow user to drag drop items from "DataGriView1" to "DataGriView2".

Thanks in advance.[image]

Answer (score 2):

Use `AllowDrop` property of `DataGridView`

```
DataGriView1.AllowDrop = false;
```

Comment: Actually i have tried this before but not worthy.
  -Thanks for help gzaxx.